# My XML is not well-formed, but where?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there any tool around that can tell me where in my docunemt I have a problem with well-formedness (if that is a word). I have a document 3.2MB large, which is not well-formed, but I cannot find anything that will assist me in locating where the problem is. I am only told that it is not well-formed, but for 3.2MB that is kind of hopeless to try and locate manually.

Comment: Try "binary delete". It's like "binary search", just more destructive.

Comment: [xmllint](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmllint/info) (part of libxml) is designed for this, and available for most platforms as part of libxml2. (It comes preinstalled on Mac OS X, so it's what I use...)

Answer (score 3):

Just open the XML file in IE or Firefox, it will show the ill-formed line.

Answer (score 1):

Most parsers (XML and other) will tell you where they got to when they failed, if you look at the error message. That may not be the actual mistake -- your problem could have been an unmatched delimiter earlier in the document, for example -- but if you look at where they say they're having trouble and what they say they're having trouble with, you can usually figure it out.

It helps to have a syntax-aware text editor which can match delimiters and/or indent the document based on its syntax; seeing something indented unexpectedly can be a huge hint about where your mistake was.

**ADDED LATER:**

Since you've said "you tried three browsers".... Try using a standalone XML parser rather than a browser. They're more likely to give you useful diagnostic information, and most of them come with simple command-line tools you could use to invoke them for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

XmlSpy is GUI tool - open the file and hit F7 - I don't know if it's available on linux or what platform you care about - I use it on windows and have a commericial version, so I'm not sure whether the freely available one has the feature.

XmlStarlet is from sourceforge, command line.

```
     $  xml val -w -e fileInQuestion.xml

val=validate
-w = well-formedness only (yes it is a word)
-e = verbose
```

I tried them both on a 20 meg file I deliberately broke and both found the error I introduced in under a second on an old laptop.